# Avoid ajax request from browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a poll on my website and it is open to anyone. The result of 'yes' or 'no' is sent via an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/bla',
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify({data1: 'yes', idquestion: '4'),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

The problem is: everyone can just go to the console and make a loop around it and make that request a thousand time. As I can't restrict by a log in system, I was wondering how I can deal with this security problem. Thanks

Comment: @dllhell I thought about that too, but I guess it is a simple matter of deleting the cookies from the console itself, so I guess it's not an optimal solution. Thanks!! :)

Comment: Verify this server-side, tied to the user account. Everything the website does the user can just copy-paste.

Comment: @millimoose I can't restrict by a user account as it is an open poll for everyone that wants to vote on it (logged or not logged) Thanks!!

Comment: Could you check the IP?  Although the IP could be spoofed.  Maybe add a captcha that must be filled out?

Comment: @AndréLucas I'd say IPs and cookies are the next best thing. You can probably either get an accurate poll, or an open one, sorry.

Comment: @millimoose hehehe I guess you are right. I think I'll have to come up with a criative solution for that

Comment: @KevinBowersox , the Captcha is an interesting solution, I'll think about that! Cheers

Comment: Captcha won't solve anything on its own; you should just track IP addresses. No matter what you try, someone will find a way to break it, so some basic checks like IP would at least force someone to send a single post, refresh their IP, send another, refresh, etc... adding more work to the act of cheating.

Comment: @CollinGrady I think a captcha would have the same effect.

Comment: Captchas would allow someone to just refresh -> enter captcha -> refresh -> enter captcha, etc - it's far simpler to type in a captcha than it is to get a new IP for many people (unless they're TOR-savvy); though doing both would add even more steps :)

Comment: @CollinGrady I guess the problem is greater to someone to run a loop and vote like 100000 times. If someone wants to vote like 10 times refreshing the IP or entering the captcha wouldn't be a problem. I'll try to find a way to mix IP and some cookie. What is coming to my mind now is that I'll have to make another table in the database to record the IPs. If the number of voters is very large I guess it would slow down the site a little. How do you suggest that data model?

Comment: It wouldn't slow things down at all, because most operations wouldn't touch the table, and those that do would only be checking for individual entries. Assuming you have a table of polls, I'd make a `pollvoted` table with `pollid|ipaddress`, I'd use `ip2long` or similar to store the IP as an int instead of a string, and use pollid/ipaddress as a composite key; then all you're doing is a very fast `SELECT 1 FROM pollvoted WHERE pollid = 4 AND ipaddress = 3232235777`; if you get a result, deny voting

Comment: @CollinGrady very nice indeed! I'll consider that! Cheers :)

Comment: @AndréLucas Generating the HTML of the site for the very large number of voters is probably slower than managing the table of IPs.